# Target closed outside of normal flow

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to automate a process with puppeteer. When adding a new feature that implied the usage of a new tab opened in a different window, I started having a `Target closed` error (stack below). I'm familiar with this error in other situations, but now I don't have a clue as to why this is happening. The version of puppeteer I'm using is `19.0.0`.
This is the error stack:

```
Target closed

      at node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/Page.ts:1599:26
      at onceHandler (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/EventEmitter.ts:130:7)
      at node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:232
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Object.emit (node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:216)
      at CDPSessionImpl.emit (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/EventEmitter.ts:118:18)
      at CDPSessionImpl._onClosed (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/Connection.ts:457:10)
      at Connection.onMessage (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/Connection.ts:164:17)
      at WebSocket.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer-core/src/common/NodeWebSocketTransport.ts:50:24)
      at WebSocket.onMessage (node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
```

When skipping the procedure that involves the usage of a second window, the error doesn't show.

This is my cleanup method, which is run when the process finished running:

```js
public async destroy() {
    let browserIsConnected: boolean = !!this._browser?.isConnected();
    if (this._browser && browserIsConnected) {
        for (let pg of await this._browser.pages()) {
            this.logger.debug(`Closing page ${pg.url()}`);
            await pg.close();
        }

        this.logger.debug(`Closing browser instance...`);
        await this._browser?.close();
        this.logger.log(`Closed browser connection`);
    } else 
        this.logger.log(`Browser already destroyed`);
    delete this._browser;
}
```

I tried omitting the `page.close()` calls but it didn't affect anything, and try/catching every library call in the method, but none throw. When running the code, the error is logged in parallel with `this._browser?.close()`, framed by the logs above and below it. However, the stack does not relate to the function call and I don't know how to catch it. Other than this, the process runs smoothly and the browser closes successfully, but this error is making my integration tests fail. Sorry about not sharing a reproducible case, but I couldn't reproduce it without disclosing my business logic.
My question is: why is this happening? is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out, and the source of this problem wasn't in the code described below but in the event handling logic during the process. While waiting the popup to show up, I was doing the following:

```js
page.once('popup', async (newPage: Page) => {
  // capture the information inside the page, with many awaits
});
```

What I didn't know was that [mitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt), puppeteer's underlying event handling library, doesn't support asynchronous event handlers, not awaiting my event properly. This was solved by resolving the promise from the handler and awaiting it further in the code:

```js
let pagePromiseResolve: Function;
let pagePromise: Promise<Page> = new Promise(resolve => {
  pagePromiseResolve = resolve;
});
page.once('popup', newPage => pagePromiseResolve(newPage));

let newPage = await pagePromise;
// capture the information inside the page, with many awaits
```

I'm leaving this here in case it helps somebody, either with this specific use-case or with awaiting events with a library alike mitt.